# Ajuste responsive para input-group con Select2 y otros form-control o input-group-btn

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap, css3, select2

Estoy tratando de terminar el diseño, para un sistema de carga de archivos: el Sistema tiene un elemento inicial `Select2`; luego se concatena con un botón de búsqueda (para buscar el archivo); luego tenemos una entrada de texto donde muestro el nombre del archivo (el campo readonly que no logro que se muestre correctamente); después de esto, necesito 3 botones: una para vista previa, otra que me permite agregar más líneas y otra que me permite eliminarlas.

pero no puedo hacer que se vea como `col-sm-12` como en `col-sm-6`
el 80% me funciona pero no es responsive

**Verifiquen el campo de entrada de texto es readonly; este tiene 80% css pero necesito que llene en todos los casos el espacio en línea a la mitad, pero no lo logro.**

```js
$(".select2").select2({
  theme: "bootstrap",
  placeholder: "Buscar y Selecionar",
  allowClear: true,
 });
```

```css
.btn-file {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}

.btn-file input[readonly] {
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: text !important;
}

.obj-file {
  width: 98% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 200px) !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}

.text-file {
  float: right !important;
  width: 60% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-theme/0.1.0-beta.9/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="input-group select2-bootstrap-append">
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <select class="form-control select2">
        <option>Selec.</option>
        <option>Prueba 2 max with</option>
        <option>Prueba 3</option>
        <option>Prueba 4</option>
        <option>Prueba 5</option>
      </select>
      <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">Buscar <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i><input id="i_file_1" type="file" name="i_file_1" accept="application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" required></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text-file" name="text_file_1" readonly>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <span class="btn btn-info btn-disabled view-doc btn-view " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-i_file_1" disabled>Vista Previa</span>
      <span class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></span>
      <span class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i></span>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

al final pude encontrar el camino correcto para hacerlo responsive:

```js
$(".select2").select2({
  theme: "bootstrap",
  placeholder: "Buscar y Selecionar",
  width: 'auto',
  dropdownAutoWidth: true,
  allowClear: true,
 });
```

```css
.btn-file {
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 0 !important;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 min-width: 100px;
 min-height: 100%;
 font-size: 100px;
 text-align: right;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0);
 opacity: 0;
 background: red;
 cursor: inherit;
 display: block;
}

.btn-file input[readonly] {
 background-color: white !important;
 cursor: text !important;
}
.text-file {
    float: right !important;
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-theme/0.1.0-beta.9/select2-bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-12 form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="input-group select2-bootstrap-append">
     <div class="input-group-btn">
      <select class="form-control select2">
       <option>Selec.</option>
       <option>Prueba 2 max with</option>
       <option>Prueba 3</option>
       <option>Prueba 4</option>
       <option>Prueba 5</option>
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="input-group-btn">
      <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">Buscar <i class="fas fa-file-alt"></i><input id="i_file_1" type="file" name="i_file_1" accept="application/pdf, image/jpeg, image/jpg, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" required></span>
     </div>
     <input type="text" class="form-control text-file" name="text_file_1" readonly>
     <div class="input-group-btn">
      <span class="btn btn-info btn-disabled view-doc btn-view " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-info-i_file_1" disabled>Vista Previa</span>
      <span class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></span>
      <span class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas fa-minus-square"></i></span>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```